# PHP - Upload file with random name from function fails

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this extremely annoying problem, the script simply doesn't want to upload the file under a new random generated name. I have rewrite the file several times without success. Anybody who knows what the problem is?

I guess it must be in this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "file/" . $new_name . '.' . $extension);
```

Here is the full script:

```
<?php

    // Generates a random filename
    function random_string($length) {

        $key = '';
        $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
        }

        if (file_exists('upload/' . $key)) {
            $key = random_string(++$length);
        }

        return $key;

    }

    // Get size of file in MB
    function filesizemb($file) {
        return number_format(filesize($file) / pow(1024, 2), 3,'.','');
    }

    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    // Get file extension
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    // Variable with new random name
    $new_name = random_string(1);

    if ($filesize < 300 * 1024 * 1024) 
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

        } else {

                // Upload the file (this fails!)
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "file/" . $new_name . '.' . $extension);    

                }

    } else {

            echo "File is too large!";

            }

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Not that I can see, I'm on my own apache2 server. Worth to mention also that everything works fine if I don't change the name. However, for safety reasons, I really need to change it.

Comment: put if condition for move_upload_file to check whats the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking whether file exists in "upload" folder, while attempting to move file to "file" folder. It might be the problem.